# My ViewControllers is not dismissing properly

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, viewcontroller

I have, three viewControllers, idea is, from ViewController to get to ViewOneController, and then ViewTwoControler, then i want to go to ViewController directly, but when i do, my memory goes up a little bit, this is the viewControllerDelegate

```
protocol ViewControllerDelegate{

func ViewControllerDidFinish(controller: ViewController)

}
```

This is viewTwo from where i am trying to go to ViewController

```
protocol ViewTwoDelegate{

func ViewTwoDidFinish(controller: ViewTwo)

}

class ViewTwo: UIViewController, ViewControllerDelegate {
    var button: UIButton!
    var delegate: ViewTwoDelegate? = nil
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
    button.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 - button.frame.size.width, 100, 250, 50)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 3
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    button.center.x = self.view.center.x
    button.setTitle("ViewController", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "ViewControllerAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    button.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    view.addSubview(button)
}

func ViewControllerAction(sender: UIButton!){
    var materialsViewController: ViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view") as! ViewController
    self.presentViewController(materialsViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func ViewControllerDidFinish(controller: ViewController){
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Other two controllers are mostly same

EDIT: i tried this

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in
        self.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    })
```

and it dismisses only itself but not presented, when i tried this

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
self.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

it works, but for two viewControllers, what if i need more?

I really need some help, please

Comment: Have you considered pushing view controllers with a navigation controller instead of presenting?  Presenting is best used for one controller that's not part of the normal flow.

Comment: i never used navigation controller, is there a way to make navigation controller without that usual blue header?

Comment: i dont know how to exactly explain it, but whenever i saw navigation Controller i saw a header at top of screen, and i dont want that

Comment: If you don't want the user to do the navigation, you should get rid of the first presented controller before putting up the second one.  (It sounds as if you're trying to fight against the way the SDK expects controllers to be used, which is never easy.)  You always have the option of defining your own container controller and your own navigation logic if the supplied models don't work for you.

Comment: thank u, i tried using navigationController and managed to work it